# Nodejs Expressjs session ip and browser agent match

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am using connect-mysql-session to store sessions in db. Now my question is how do i add user data containing browser agent and ip-adress to check if the  session is valid? How do i obtain that information? And how do i check if it matches?

```
    users.login(credentials,function(err, results) {

  //On errors
  if (err) {
    res.render(routes.index, {
      title: 'Login'
    });

  //On success
  } else if (results[0]) {
    //Set session data and redirect to start page
    req.session.userdata = results[0];
    req.session.userdata.email = req.body.email_login;
    req.session.is_logged_in = true;
    res.redirect('/start');

  //Wrong credentials
  } else {
    req.flash('warning','Wrong password or login');
    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Login'
    });
  }
});
```

**Update:**

I now got this added to the session:

```
req.session.ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
req.session.useragent = req.headers['user-agent'];
```

and check for it in my auth middleware:

```
  if(req.session.userdata && req.session.is_logged_in === true && req.session.ip === req.connection.remoteAddress && req.session.useragent === req.headers['user-agent']) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
```

Is this secure or do you see any risks with this? Should i go about it another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation looks good, and will give you some - very - basic protection against session hijacking.

However, I'm not sure I understand your middleware. What prevents an user from requesting `/start` directly? And, more importantly, as the middleware intercepts all requests, even those for `/start`, doesn't this look like some infinite redirect loop?

My suggestion would simply be to consider a user logged out at all time when ip or user agent mismatches.

Comment: You are right about the infinite loop. I edited the code, paste issues.

And what are your suggestions on making this more secure in terms of hijacking. As you said it is very basic, but I really don't know what else i have to protect from? Any hints or tips appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Pages are transferred over https by the way.

Comment: With pages transferred over HTTPS, you're definitely good to go, and you have strong protection against this. This definitely was the missing information. The only additional advise I'd make would be to set the `secure` flag in your session cookie, so it can only be transferred over an HTTPS connection. This will prevent an user mistakenly requesting an non-secure page to expose the session cookie in clear.